# How to install package with dependent libraries into separate directory

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I've been using suse for a long time. On a new computer I've install ubuntu 18.04, but it lacks wavegain package in repositories. So I've try install wavegain from downloaded rpm.

```
root@1201HA:/home/user/Downloads# rpm -i wavegain-1.3.1-3.13.x86_64.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
warning: wavegain-1.3.1-3.13.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f23c6aa3: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by wavegain-1.3.1-3.13.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
    libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by wavegain-1.3.1-3.13.x86_64
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by wavegain...
```

I have old hard disk with suse and wavegain on it. My intention is copy wavegain with all dependent libraries into /home/user/bin.
But there is no listed libraries on my suse? How can it be?

My question: is it possible use wavegain and dependent libraries on separate directory at all? Wavegain and dependent libraries in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Add it your path!

1. Change to your home directory.

```bsh
cd $HOME
```

2. Open the .bashrc file.
3. Add the following line to the file.  The path should be to the directory containing your `libc.so.6` dependencies.

```bsh
export PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH
```

4. Save the file and exit.

Comment: Does just copy /usr/lib/libc.so.6 from suse to  ubuntu /home/user/bin/libc.so.6? So simple?